# Selenium not retrieving the current text value of an element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a testing application in C# using Selenium and ChromeDriver. I have a web page that loads the contents of several tables using AJAX, and my test wants to see a specific string loaded somewhere into one of those tables. I can see the string on my screen when I do the test manually with the same parameters, but Selenium doesn't see it.

The test waits for jQuery to start and then finish, then queries the text value of the table to see if anything matches the test string. Here's the problem: When it queries the table's text value, via the innerHTML, innerText, textContent and value attributes, or the .Text property of the element, it doesn't see the text that was loaded via AJAX. It sees the original table which is just the headers. So it looks like either Selenium didn't grab the latest value from the page, AJAX wasn't done before Selenium grabbed it, or something else is wrong. How can I debug this or write my query more correctly?

For my initial debugging effort, I've first verified that the correct table has been selected, and that jQuery did in fact start and finish, then set up logging like so, and all of these lines produce similar output with the initial headers-only version of the table:

```
log.Trace(".Text: {0}", selectedElement.Text);
log.Trace("attr innerHTML: {0}", selectedElement.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
log.Trace("attr innerText: {0}", selectedElement.GetAttribute("innerText"));
log.Trace("attr textContent: {0}", selectedElement.GetAttribute("textContent"));
log.Trace("attr value: {0}", selectedElement.GetAttribute("value"));
```

The code waits for jQuery to start and then finish via this (slightly simplified from the actual implementation which compares against an object's ToString and works great elsewhere):

```
string js = "return !!window.jQuery && window.jQuery.active == 0";
waiter.Until(_ => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_).ExecuteScript(js)
    .ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals("FALSE"));
waiter.Until(_ => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_).ExecuteScript(js)
    .ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals("TRUE"));
```

The only thing I can think of right now is that maybe the AJAX for that specific table hasn't processed but jQuery came back as finished? That possibility doesn't make much sense, but I don't know how to test it to be sure.

I would prefer not to modify the site itself, but keep all of the test-related pieces in the C# test suite, if at all possible.

edit: I can see the values by inspecting the elements in Chrome - the textContent property in the Inspector is correct - but Selenium simply doesn't pick it up with my current code. I'm having no trouble selecting the table itself since Selenium picks up its unique header text every time. Since it's been asked, here is a sanitized version of the table in question, which is buried deeply into the page, and has a unique ID which I'm using to select it along the lines of By.CssSelector("#thetable"):

```
<table id='thetable'>
  <colgroup> ... 5x <col> tags ... </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr> ... 5x <th> tags ... </tr>
    <tr> ... 5x <th> tags ... </tr>
    <tr><th colspan='5'...> ...</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> ... 5x <td> tags, one of which includes the text I look for ... </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The previously-mentioned properties & attributes of the table element itself only give me the text from the thead section.

Comment: As you have mentioned innerHTML, innerText, textContent and value attributes, or the .Text property , can you provide the HTML code , so that we can give the optimum solution.

Comment: Edited, provided as much as I could reasonably provide given the sensitive nature of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.

The problem is, when you query those text attributes on the `table` element, they delve into the `thead` element and then return before also going into the `tbody` element. This is verifiable in-browser on our site using the JS console. I'm not sure why this is, nor do I have time to search for that information, but it is that way currently. (7/2018, Chrome 67)

No amount of waiting changes that behavior.

The solution was to use a selector with `tbody` appended, such as `.thetable tbody` instead of `.thetable` and now it picks up the correct text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for the specific text, I recommend waiting for the text instead of waiting for Javascript execution.

See my code below:

```
public void TestWaitForText()
{
    IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
    wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
    wait.Until(d => isAnyTextAppeared(d));
}

private Boolean isAnyTextAppeared(IWebDriver d)
{
    List<string> textList = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar" };
    foreach(var txt in textList)
    {
        var elems = d.FindElements(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'" + txt +"')]"));
        if (elems.Count > 0)
        {
            log.Trace(".Text: {0}", elems[0].Text);
            return true;
        }                    
    }
    return false;
}
```